# Android TCP socket client/server implementation

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, inputstream

I'm new to Java and Android, I'm trying to create a server/client application. For the moment I'm running the server on the PC and the client is on an Android device. The communication takes place and all works fine, but I want to differentiate incoming messages from the client in order to do different actions on the server. Here's the code for the server. The client is pretty easy and works well. For example when I send "Name" from the client, the serve should answer with "Matteo" but it always answers with "Something else" and I can't understand why! I imagine that the problem is in the statement `if (dataInputStream.equals("Name")) {`

Thank you.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Server1 {

 public static void main(String[] args){
  ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  Socket socket = null;
  DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
  DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

  try {
   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
   System.out.println("Listening on port 8888");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  while(true){
   try {
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
    dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress() + " : " + dataInputStream.readUTF());

    if (dataInputStream.equals("Name")) {
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Matteo!");

    }
    else if (dataInputStream.equals("Surname")) {
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Rossi!");

    }
    else {
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Something else!");

    }
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally{
    if( socket!= null){
     try {
      socket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    if( dataInputStream!= null){
     try {
      dataInputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    if( dataOutputStream!= null){
     try {
      dataOutputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`DataInputStream` represents the handle to stream of data coming from the socket, but not the data itself. So `.equals()` compares it with another `DataInputStream` not with a `String`. You are comparing it directly with a string, which obviously returns `false`.

Just like you are writing data with `writeUTF()`, you need to read data from the socket connection through that `DataInputStream`. Use one of the `read()` methods described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) or if you know that your client will send whole lines, you can wrap it in a `BufferedReader` and use the following:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInputStream));
String input = bufferedReader.readLine();
if (input.equals("Name")
{
  dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Matteo!");
}
else ...
```

On another note, in Java 7, you can use `switch` statements on String too, instead of `.equals()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, using this solution the communication doesn't work at all, in the sense that the server receives the massage from the client but it doesn't reply to the client, nor "Something else".

Comment: If you are using this solution, your client has to send a new line separator at the end of the message for readLine() to work. So it has to send "name\n". Otherwise the server keeps waiting for the \n. So this solution is only good if the client sends whole lines. (i.e. separated by the newline \n separator). Otherwise use the `read()` methods provided by the `DataInputStream`  described in the page of URL I provided.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is that you should [*read*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) something from the `DataInputStream`. Eg.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[ 1024 ];
dataInputStream.read( buffer );
if ( new String( buffer ).equals( "Name" ) ) { /*  do your stuff */ }
```

This is *much* abbreviated, but you could work from there.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look into an `ObjectInputStream` you can then read the object and use the:

```
instanceof
```

keyword to differntiate between objects